# Openshift trustwave intermediate ssl cert issue

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, openshift

So I have got an application on openshift and I am trying to enable SSL on there. I already have an SSL cert from my previous host which is with Trustwave and seemed to work fine.

So I have setup an alias for `my-domain.com` and have put a CNAME redirect on the domain provider to openshift and that works fine. Now I was provided a zip file full of different file formats for the cert:

- my-domain.com.cer
- my-domain.com.der
- my-domain.com.p7b
- my-domain.com.pem
- chain.cer

I have got a private key as well in a .pem file, and it seems to all setup fine, using the `my-domain.com.pem`, `chain.cer` and `my-private-key.pem`. However if I then go to any of the SSL analysis sites they all say the same, that there is no intermediate cert, and it even seems to think I am not using a trustwave cert, which I most certainly am. I know openshift uses SNI so I am not really to worried about the `*.rhcloud.com` issue, but I am baffled as to why it thinks my cert is not from trustwave (when it is) and why it cannot find intermediates.

Most browsers other than FF dont care about this and work fine showing the padlock, but Firefox shows the invalid SSL screen and warns the user rather than showing the site.

I have tried going to the trustwave site and downloading their intermediate certs `dvca2.crt` but even trying that still gives same issue.

I am a bit baffled as to why it doesnt work, I have tried the other file types in the zip file such as the `my-domain.com.cer` but still same thing. So I am out of ideas and wondering if anyone else has had similar issues or knows what could be causing it.

[image: Example feedback from SSL analysis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok solve it after lots of searching, and Trustwave still reports it as wrong but all browsers seem to accept it.

So I got the main cert file (I was using `my-domain.com.pem`) copy and paste the contents into a new file (something like `combined.pem`) then open your intermediate file (`chain.cer` for me) and copy and paste this into the end of your combined file, so it should look like:

```
-- Begin Cert
...
-- End Cert
-- Begin Cert
...
-- End Cert
```

Then upload this new combined file as your main cert file to openshift, ignore the chain file and add your private key. Should all work now.